# Send to Google Maps with one Location

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, coordinates

I'm developing an Android app and I need to give the user directions to reach some places. I have the coordinates of the places but I find pretty hard to get the user current location, to bypass this I was wondering if I can send the user to Google Maps indicating only the coordinates of the place he wants to reach, will Google Maps give correct directions to the user or I must specify also his location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a hack I just found out to achieve what you want.

```
String directionsUrl = "https://www.google.co.in/maps/dir/'" + sourceLat + "," + sourceLng + "'/'" + destLat + "," + destLng + "'/";
```

Then just use an `Intent` to open up the URL.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(directionsUrl));
startActivity(intent);
```

Then Android will provide the list of apps that can perform the action and then it's just a matter of choosing Google Maps.

Comment: Thanks! :) I was hoping for Google Maps itself to get the user current location but no problem, i'll find a way to get the Location and pass it to the string

Comment: I think you shouldn't have much trouble getting the current location info using the `LocationManager` class. Plotting the route is the trickier bit.

Answer (score 0):

This will be helpful to you.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=srclatitude,srclongitude&daddr=destlat,destlong"));
startActivity(intent);
```